# Separate Intersected layers (as points)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, intersection, hydrography, rivers, catchment-area

I'm trying to establish watershed outlets as points with two shape files that I have available;

1. The watersheds polygons
2. The river network

As I said above I'm trying to define the outlets but due to geometry reasons of the river network (which touches the boundaries of the watershed) as a result I take the following pictures.

[image]

[image]

You can see that the true outlets can be defined but due to the geometry issues they cannot be separated as unique points with 1-1 relationship with the catchments.
I tried the smooth polygon and poly-line toolboxes and they seem to have worked quite well.

[image]
[image]

Another issue is that when I'm trying to select only the catchments for experimentation it selects all the upstream points with the multiple attributes also in the table shared as multiple records. This issue partially solved by the "Multipart to Singlepart" toolbox and now I'm exploring the impacts in the attribute tables or how to solve any double or multi - records still remain

Comment: I see the geometry issue. If you can't smooth the catchment boundaries, you *might* be able to get around that by using Feature Vertices to Points on the river network (possibly only doing start/end nodes, not sure how broken up your river lines are), then selecting only those resulting points which touch the boundary of catchments (assuming they are polygons, because you couldn't use intersect if so). I'm not following the rest of your question regarding attributes - do you have an issue with multipoints or just a lack of unique attributes? Maybe a screenshot of your tables would help?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I came to a probably strange solution to select the outlets.

I took the river polyline and converted it to a raster. All river-cells got the value 1. Then I made a Cost-Distance analysis from the river mouth with the river raster as cost surface. So each point of the resulting raster represents the distance to from the cell to the river mouth.

Finally I extracted the distance values to the points and selected the points with the smallest distance value for each watershed.

I hope it is more helping than confusing :-).

Comment: +1 because I though to suggest very similar, but vector based solution

Comment: I used the Toolbox> Data Management > Features > Multipart to Singlepart  tool where all the multi-points transformed into single-parts releasing the number of duplicate values where I managed to some extend clean them through the attributes after matched with queries in MS Access. I think it cannot be solved to a higher level due to the geometry issues.